# Stuck on this probability question?

Tags: statistics

In a multiple choice test paper let us assume there are $m$ possible answers, if a person knows the correct answer to a question then they will mark the correct answer and that if they don't know it they will randomly guess. There is a probability of $k$ that a person will know the correct answer to the question.

Find out the probability that a person knew the correct answer given that they marked the correct answer.

Here is all I have.

$$P(Guessing~Correctly)=\frac{1}{m}$$
$$P(Guessing~Incorrectly)=\frac{m-1}{m}$$
$$P(Knowing~Answer)=k$$
$$P(Not~Knowing~Answer)=1-k$$

$$P(Knew~Answer|Marked~Right~Answer)=?$$

But I am unsure how to proceed . Any help? Thanks.

Comment: After playing around I manged to get $$\frac{km}{k+m}$$ can anyone verify?

Comment: One can verify it is not right. Suppose $k=1$, the person knows everything. Then the probability she knows given she got the right answer is $1$, which is not what the above formula gives.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ denote "Marks the right answer" and $K$ denote "Knows the answer". We have been told
$$
P(K) = k\\
P(M\mid\overline K) = \frac{1}{m}\\
P(M \mid K) = 1
$$
With this we should be able to calculate $P(M)$:
$$
P(M) = P(M\mid K)\cdot P(K) + P(M\mid \overline K)\cdot P(\overline K)\\
= k + \frac{1-k}{m}\\
= \frac{km - k + 1}{m}
$$
And finally we can calculate $P(K\mid M)$ using Bayes' theorem
$$
P(K\mid M) = \frac{P(M\mid K)\cdot P(K)}{P(M)}\\
= \frac{1\cdot k}{\frac{km-k+1}{m}}\\
= \frac{km}{km-k+1}\\
= 1 - \frac{1-k}{km - k +1}
$$

Comment: Why isn't $P(M|K)=1$? When if we are given that they know the answer they will mark it down correctly?

Comment: @Peter But it is, and my answer says so, right at the top, third line of math, below $P(M\mid \overline K) = 1/m$, and above "With this we should be able to..."